# How can I make Coldfusion Reactor ignore some columns in a table

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, reactor

I'm using Coldfusion 10 + Reactor in project. I add a new TIMESTAMP field which will auto updated to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. It works when this new field is not included into Reactor objects, e.g. Dao, To, Record. but it will be failed once regenerate ColdFusion objects.

so how can I ignore the new field in reactor?

Here are the related code

```
<object name="Object">
    <hasOne name="XXXX">
        <relate from="KeyUUID" to="KeyUUID"/>
    </hasOne>
    ...
</object>
```

After I regenerated ColdFusion objects, the create/update method in ObjectDao.cfc will include my new field. The ObjectDao.cfc is regenerated by Reactor according to my database table. I want this new field excluded from Reactor objects, e.g. Dao, To, Record.

```
<cfquery name="qCreate" datasource="#_getConfig().getDsn()#" username="#_getConfig().getUsername()#" password="#_getConfig().getPassword()#">
    INSERT INTO #Convention.FormatObjectName(getObjectMetadata())#
    (
            ...
            #Convention.formatInsertFieldName('newField', 'Object')#

    ) VALUES (
            ...
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"

            value="#arguments.to.newField#"

                null="#Iif(NOT Len(arguments.to.lastModifiedDBTime), DE(true), DE(false))#"
             /> 
    )
    ...
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to go along with this?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I added some code, but most of them are generated by Reactor. I want to know how I can configure the reactor.xml to ignore the new column. Many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactorORM/reactor/wiki/Staff it seems that  Ignore fields not Implemented yet!

Answer (score 1):

We implement this by update ObjectDao.cfc for now.

```
<cffunction name="readFields" access="private" hint="I populate the table with fields." output="false" returntype="void">
...
    <cfloop query="qFields">
        <cfset blnProcess = true />
        <cfif structKeyExists(stcFieldsToSkip,arguments.Object.getName())>
           <cfif qFields.FIELD EQ stcFieldsToSkip[arguments.Object.getName()]>
               <cfset blnProcess = false />
           </cfif>
        </cfif>
        <cfif blnProcess>
            <!---
            mod by SPJ: in MySql 4 tinytext, text, mediumtext and longtext don't report their maxlength value, so we
            have to set it by hand.  The field lengths were obtained from http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/mysqlEZinfo/data_types.html#Storage_requirements
        --->
            <cfswitch expression="#qFields.TYPE#">
                ...
            </cfswitch>
            <!--- end mod by SPJ --->

            <!--- create the field --->
            ...

            <!--- add the field to the table --->
            <cfset arguments.Object.addField(Field) />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```